# Create equation with two numbers

Tags: math, combinatorics

I need a formula to define the relation between the length of a list in this example (2) and  the number of elements which is here (4) to calculate the number of combinations which is (10).

Example:

```
(1,1)   
(1,2)  
(1,3)  
(1,4)  
(2,2)  
(2,3)  
(2,4)  
(3,3)  
(3,4)  
(4,4)
```

Comment: There's err.. more than `4` elements in this list..

Comment: i mean from that the list counts from 1 to 4

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Math.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation should be,

```
f(n) = n*(n+1) / 2, f(n) is length
```

f(4) = 4 * 5 / 2 = 10

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you derive the formula.

There are 4 entries with one as the first component: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), 3 entries with two in the first component, 2 with three and 1 with four.

That's 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.  If you have 5 elements, it's 1 + 2 + 3 + 5, if you have 2 elements, it's 1 + 2.

It's clear we need a formula to evaluate 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n

[image: Gauss' trick]

By rearranging the sum, we get terms that all evaluate to `n + 1`, since we always grouped two numbers, we have `n/2` such terms. Hence `n/2 * (n + 1)`